# removeClass and keep effect transition jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a trouble about `transition: all 1s;`
It appears only when I `mouseover` but for `mouseout`, no effect appear.

I use `jQuery` like this

```js
$(".menu-inside ul").on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 1) {
    $('.menu').addClass('lightactive');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('lightactive');
  }
}).on('mouseout', function(){           
 
});
```

```css
.menu .level1 {
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  width:0;
}
.menu.lightactive .level1 {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:25;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
  <div class="gothic menu-center" id="menu-center">
    <div class="menu-inside">
      <div class="mn-btn">
        <div class="menubtn">
          <p class="btnmn">
            <span class="m1"></span>
            <span class="m2"></span>
            <span class="m3"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="" href="#header"><span>01</span><span>Menu1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" class="active"><span>02</span><span>Menu2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#quote"><span>03</span><span>Menu3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#work"><span>04</span><span>Menu4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level1"></div>
  <div class="level2"></div>
</div>
```

`.menu` is parent box. thank you so much for any helps.

Comment: ah. sorry. please wait me

Comment: Add a transition on the class having the other state.

Comment: can you add your answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only `width` in `lightactive` class and others inside `menu` class itself. So it would show the width transition well. another thing is use `mouseover` event inplace of `mousemove`

**Note:-**

On mouse move it is still open and close. It is not because of mousemove. but because of your mask layer is outside of the event target (`level1`)

```js
$(".menu-inside ul").on('mouseover', function(e) {
  if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 1) {
    $('.menu').addClass('lightactive');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('lightactive');
  }
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  if ($('.menu').hasClass('lightactive')) {
    $('.menu').removeClass('lightactive');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu .level1 {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:25;
}
.menu.lightactive .level1 {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
  <div class="gothic menu-center" id="menu-center">
    <div class="menu-inside">
      <div class="mn-btn">
        <div class="menubtn">
          <p class="btnmn">
            <span class="m1"></span>
            <span class="m2"></span>
            <span class="m3"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="" href="#header"><span>01</span><span>Menu1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" class="active"><span>02</span><span>Menu2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#quote"><span>03</span><span>Menu3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#work"><span>04</span><span>Menu4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level1"></div>
  <div class="level2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. it is actual best solution. I will check you as best person :)

Comment: Welcome. [**Upvote**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/342523) the answer if it helped. :)